# Activity with another activity of dialog theme on top

Tags: android

I have integrated an SDK which allows push notifications to shown as a sticky banner on top of my Activity. On debugging I found that how the SDK achieves this is by launching another activity with Dialog theme on top my current activity and showing the banner in it. The problem is that when user is interacting with my previous Activity (which is the feature needed ie sticky banner) and clicks on any of the buttons to add/remove a fragment, app crashes as the previous activity in onPause state. What would be the ideal way to fix this?

Comment: What is the crash cause? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Crash is occuring since commiting/popping a fragment is not allowed post onSaveInstance()